# Spring Batch Admin existing jobs are not launchable anymore after new job registration

Tags: spring-batch, spring-batch-admin

Currently, I'm stuck with the integration of Spring Batch Admin (SBA) into our project cause of a problem I couldn't resolve. Hopefully, someone have an advice for me.

We use the sample SBA application (current version from Github) and added just a Tasklet. I upload Spring Batch descriptions (XMLs) via the */job-configuration.json* API of SBA using. This works fine as expected. In the HTML pages of SBA, I see that the job registered and is launchable. It can be executed via the API (/jobs/{jobName}.json) and over the web interface.

The problem is, if I upload a new job, it is registered and launchable as well. But the job registered before becomes automatically "*launchable = false*". It couldn't be executed anymore.

I couldn't find any documentation about this behaviour nor any solution to avoid. Can you give me an direction what could be wrong?

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

I couldn't get it working. My workaround is now

1) Upload the job data as XML file using the */job-configuration* API method (POST, mutipart). This solves the problem that the job stays launchable also after multiple uploads.

2) I manually uploaded the XML files to *WEB-INF\classes\META-INF\spring\batch\jobs*, thus, the jobs are executable also after a re-sarted.

It's not nice, but works. I still appreciate any other more elegant solution.

Comment: Two questions: 1.  Have you verified in the directory the files are being written that they both are there?  2.  Do the jobs have unique ids?

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your reply.

 1) No, there are no files written. As I can see,

Comment: Sorry, "entered" to fast...

Hi. Thanks for your reply.

 1) No, there are no files written. As I can see, job information is just stored in the DB. Where should they been stored? I recognized 2 folders: a) WEB-INF\classes\META-INF\spring\batch\jobs and b) batch.job.configuration.file.dir=target/config Both are untouched after an upload.

2) Yes. Jobs as well as the inherit steps have always unique ids.

Answer (score 0):

You could register job factory to JobRegistry

```
@Autowired
private JobRegistry jobRegistry;

protected JobFactory factory;

@PostConstruct
public void init() throws DuplicateJobException {
    factory = new JobFactory() {

        @Override
        public Job createJob() {
            return job();   //your job creation logic
        }

        @Override
        public String getJobName() {
            return jobName();   
        }

    };
    jobRegistry.register(factory);
}

//for your own launcher
protected void run() throws Exception {
    jobLauncher.run(factory.createJob(), parameters().toJobParameters());
}
```